# how to remove this #.XsZOUWhKjIU from my wordpress url

Tags: urls

i need help on how to remove this line of code #.XsZOUWhKjIU on my WordPress link, sometimes the code changes but the #. remains the same, whenever i click on a post that code will attach to the link like example.com/best-club-in-the-world/#.XsZOUWhKjIU

Comment: I'd start by working out if this is being generated by WordPress or by a script: try fetching a page using curl or something similar and check the links in the HTML there, before any script has had a chance to run. If the hashes are there in that HTML then WordPress is generating this: look through your list of plugins and try disabling them until you can narrow down what's doing it - I'd guess an analytics plugin. If it's not done in WordPress, i.e. it's a script, then actually it's probably still worth trying to disable plugins or trying a default theme to work out what's generating them.

Comment: I have disabled almost all plugins, but I still have analytics plugins I haven't tried disabling, let me give it a try